# Align buttons horizontally

Tags: html

I am trying to build my portfolio website and I dont have any prior knowledge of html. I am trying to align buttons horizontally on the webpage and was hoping I could get some help on how I can edit this piece of code to fix this alignment issue.

[Webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xma9.png)

Below is the code snippet:

```
<article>
   <header>
      <h2><a href="#">Labeling using<br />
         Weak Supervision</a>
      </h2>
   </header>
   <a href="#" class="image fit"><img src="images/Snorkel-AI.png" alt="" width =auto height =auto /></a>
   <p>Snorkel is a system for programmatically building and managing training datasets using the concept of weak supervision. This use cases demonstrates programtically labeling of text messages as spam or non-spam using snorkel.</p>
   <ul class="actions special">
      <li><a href="https://github.com/tauseef1234/Spam_Labeling_Snorkel/blob/main/SMS_Snorkel.ipynb" class="button">GitHub</a></li>
   </ul>
</article>
<article>
   <header>
      <h2><a href="#">Traffic Sign <br />
         Detection</a>
      </h2>
   </header>
   <a href="#" class="image fit"><img src="images/traffic.png" alt="" width =auto height =auto /></a>
   <p>In this project, I use TensorFlow to build a neural network to classify road signs based on an image of those signs. For this project, the German Traffic Sign Recognition Benchmark (GTSRB) dataset was used that contains thousands of images of 43 different kinds of road signs. </p>
   <ul class="actions special">
      <li><a href="https://github.com/tauseef1234/Traffic_CNN" class="button">GitHub</a></li>
   </ul>
</article>
```

I tried adding extra spaces but that required lot of editing in the existing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work with the flex-box. Add `text-align: center` to align them vertically centered.

```css
/* Put all of the bottom code */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  display: flex;
}

section article {
  width: 50%;
  /* -------------- */
  text-align: center;
  /* ----- or ----- / */
  /*** display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center ***/
  /* -------------- */
}
```

```html
<section class="container"> <!-- Put this line -->
  <article>
    <header>
      <h2><a href="#">Labeling using<br />
         Weak Supervision</a>
      </h2>
    </header>
    <a href="#" class="image fit"><img src="images/Snorkel-AI.png" alt="" width=auto height=auto /></a>
    <p>Snorkel is a system for programmatically building and managing training datasets using the concept of weak supervision. This use cases demonstrates programtically labeling of text messages as spam or non-spam using snorkel.</p>
    <ul class="actions special">
      <li><a href="https://github.com/tauseef1234/Spam_Labeling_Snorkel/blob/main/SMS_Snorkel.ipynb" class="button">GitHub</a></li>
    </ul>
  </article>
  <article>
    <header>
      <h2><a href="#">Traffic Sign <br />
         Detection</a>
      </h2>
    </header>
    <a href="#" class="image fit"><img src="images/traffic.png" alt="" width=auto height=auto /></a>
    <p>In this project, I use TensorFlow to build a neural network to classify road signs based on an image of those signs. For this project, the German Traffic Sign Recognition Benchmark (GTSRB) dataset was used that contains thousands of images of 43 different
      kinds of road signs. </p>
    <ul class="actions special">
      <li><a href="https://github.com/tauseef1234/Traffic_CNN" class="button">GitHub</a></li>
    </ul>
  </article>
</section> <!-- Put this line -->
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do I simply add the 1st code snippet before my code snippet? Sorry I am very naive in css/html.

Comment: I edited the answer and recognized which lines you should put. Much appreciated if you accepted the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: Thank you again. After adding the edits, I am still not able to fix this issue. I am sharing the link to the entire code. https://github.com/tauseef1234/tauseef1234.github.io/blob/main/projects.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `text-align: center;` or

```
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
```